# React Native Modalbox doesn't centered on phone that setting with right to left language

Tags: reactjs, react-native, right-to-left

I have an issue with modalbox that doesn't centered.
My virtual android set on right to left language such as Hebrew ,Arabic or Tamashek, and when I setup a modalbox (modal centered) with on react native app, the modal window stick to the right side of the screen, did anyone knows how to fix this issue?
I need the modal in the middle of the screen like "position centered + backdrop".
https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox

Thanks